# Jslint shows Syntax Error where none exists - SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: jslint

I am getting a strange SytaxError with JSLint

I have a file with no code except:
    var a = function(){
          if(isChecked())
             { }
            };

And I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
      if(isChecked())
......^
```

I made another file with only if(Math.Round()) { alert('here');}, and I get

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
if(Math.Round()) { alert('here');}
....................^
```

I built jslint for Ubuntu and the error does not appear on the online lint site. I just need to ignore this error, but /*jsl:ignore*/ does not work (maybe because it is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is some kind of encoding error. If I write this code myself, there is no error, but if the code is copy and pasted from a document which had an error, then these errors ensue.

The solution is to re-type the code and save the file.